# Is there reason to use Cygwin over Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, bash, cygwin, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Installed Cygwin a few years ago for things like `grep`, `git` and basically anything that works well in the bash commandline. installed the Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10 program recently and it's basically a Linux distro operating on top of windows 10. It does everything that I used to use Cygwin for.

Maybe I don't know Cygwin well enough, but at the moment I don't see any reason to keep it installed on my system. Does Cygwin have any advantages over Bash on Ubuntu on Windows?

Comment: You are asking an opinion, as such everyone one has a different view and not exact answer exists.  see as example discussion on https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2016-08/msg00570.html

Comment: @matzeri Maybe the question was formulated badly. Basically, I am wondering what the advantages are of Cygwin over 'Bash on Ubuntu on Window' program. There are plenty of similar questions, like the classic 'programming language 1 vs programming language 2' type questions.

From your link, I could make out that 'Bash on Ubuntu on Windows' is like a Linux VM, while Cygwin is more of a native approach.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are some practical advantages of Cygwin at this time: (1)you can execute .exe files; (2)you can access files which are prohibited to WSL/Bash due to Windows 10 security.

Comment: Also cygwin toolchain will build you a windows executable, whereas bash toolchaing will build you an linux executable. And sometimes the resulting linux executable (depending on how your make process is defined) won't run on WSL properly.

Comment: Do the above remarks still hold true? I have heard that one can get around each of these now...

Comment: Main reason for me is to build windows executables so this is a perfect answer. Also, I highly recommend setting up your cygwin with this article: https://guysherman.com/2013/11/02/my-ultimate-cygwin-setup/